# how to remove the % sign from the formula result in excel

Tags: excel

I have an excel file and the formula for the E2 cell is as follows:
=(B2*C2*(1-D2))/100
But the thing is the D2 cell's content is a pursuantage like 7% and then bc of that it writes the result in E2 cell also with a % sign next to it!
How can i remove it?
(sorry!I'm such a beginner with excel!)

Comment: change the cell format to whatever you want

Answer (score 0):

In  the top menus youll find find a setting you could change formats...alternative. highlight the cell you want to change format...  type the following control+shift+~  that should do it